# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. Occurs when my form class tries to access the database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

That's the error I'm currently getting. I tried looking at previous threads about it but they confused me. Here's the relevant python code:

```py
class Quiz(FlaskForm):

    submit = SubmitField()
    questions = get_questions()
    for question in questions:
        vars()[question["skill"]] = RadioField(u"{}".format(question["question"]),
                                               choices=[("0", "Strongly disagree"), ("0", "Disagree"),
                                                        ("1", "Neither agree nor disagree"), ("2", "Agree"),
                                                        ("3", "Strongly agree")])
def get_questions():
    questions = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT skill, question FROM questions'
    ).fetchall()
    return questions
```

I'm using vars() to dynamically add attributes to the class at creation. If I replace questions = get_questions() with questions = [{"skill":"skill","question":"question"},{"skill":"skill1","question":"question1"}] for example then it works perfectly. get_questions() simply accesses the questions table and grabs the question and corresponding skill from each row. The problem arises when questions calls get_db() and then specifically on the line if 'db' not in g.

```py
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db
```

Here's the lines leading up to the error:

```
class Quiz(FlaskForm):

questions = get_questions()

questions = get_db().execute(

if 'db' not in g:
```

that's where I get the error RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

I'm not sure why it's happening. It happens no matter which webpage I load. Could it be that classes can't access the database, only functions?

Edit:

```
File "x", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "x", line 83, in find_best_app
app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)
File "x", line 119, in call_factory
return app_factory()
from . import website
File "x", line 135, in <module>
class Quiz(FlaskForm):
File "x", line 144, in Quiz
questions = get_questions()
File "x", line 130, in get_questions
questions = get_db().execute(
File "x", line 9, in get_db
if 'db' not in g:
File "x", line 379, in <lambda>
__contains__ = lambda x, i: i in x._get_current_object()
File "x", line 306, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "x", line 45, in _lookup_app_object
raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)

RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback message?

Comment: Plus, where is the instance of your app context in this code?, Did you import it or created in this code?, you are trying to access DB outside app context (hence the error message)

Comment: Just edited my post to include the full traceback. Sorry but I'm not quite sure what you mean by the instance of my app. I create the app using flask in my \_\_init\_\_.py file and host it locally on my computer. The code in my post is located in my website.py and db.py files.

Comment: I put the class inside the function and it works fine now. I think it's because the class is trying to access the database without being part of a flask function.